# Mocking forms in view unit tests

Tags: django, django-forms, mocking, django-unittest

I can't seem to be able to mock the behaviour of a form when unit testing views.

My form is a simple ModelForm and resides in `profiles.forms`. The view is (again) a simple view that checks whether the form is valid and then redirects.

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from profiles.forms import ProfileForm

def home(request):
    form = ProfileForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("thanks"))
```

My test looks like this:

```
class TestViewHomePost(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

    def test_form(self):
        with mock.patch('profiles.views.ProfileForm') as mock_profile_form:
            mock_profile_form.is_valid.return_value = True
            request = self.factory.post(reverse("home"), data={})
            response = home(request)
            logger.debug(mock_profile_form.is_valid.call_count)    # "0"
```

`is_valid` is not being called on the mock, which means ProfileForm is not patched.

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix mocking `is_valid` as following:

```
def test_form(self):
        with mock.patch('profiles.views.ProfileForm.is_valid') as mock_profile_form:
            mock_profile_form.return_value = True
            request = self.factory.post(reverse("home"), data={})
            response = home(request)
```

note: and you could use `mock_profile_form.assert_called_once()` to check if the mock has been called.